# How to add "powered by google logo" at the end of autocomplete query result?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I've implemented Google's places autocomplete view in my app. As the documentation says I've to put a "powered by Google" logo at the end of query result.(See: image below). That's why I wanted to know how I can add that logo at the end, of places list. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Implementation of what I want to achieve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in search of Google places autocomplete.

I figured Google has the Place **Autocomplete** service using which I can allow the user to type in a city name which’ll fetch all the cities containing that string from Google’s servers that can be presented in an **AutoCompleteTextView**.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the list_item.xml as you see in :

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/

to include the Powered By Google Image for your auto complete.

Hope this helps.